# Bluemix Push REST API messages report details

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to see why one of my apps is failing at delivering push notifications to iOS devices.
On the [Push REST API doc page](https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfpush) I saw that there was the GET `/apps/{applicationId}/messages/{messageId}/report` endpoint which I could use but it seems that there is little information given with that.

As a result to GET `https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2cc73363-b50f-4b60-b2f9-c483ff5cd414/messages/8d58f4e/report` I only get

```
{
  "invalid": 2,
  "sent": 2,
  "ios": {
    "invalid": 2,
    "sent": 2
  }
}
```

for a push sent to 2 ios device.

Is there a way to get more information on why the push delivery has failed/was invalid? Do you have another endpoint where I can get additional info?

Comment: How are you trying to send the push notifications to your devices?  Are you able to send notifications to your devices from the Push console or the REST API Swagger Doc?

Comment: I tried it with the REST API Swagger Doc 
POST /apps/{applicationId}/messages and that's how I got the message id in the response to my POST
{
  "message": {
    "message": {
      "alert": "Test"
    }
  },
  "messageId": "8d58f4e"
}

Comment: Are you using a sandbox or production certificate for iOS push notifications?  Are you able to see registered iOS devices using GET /apps/{applicationId}/devices?

Comment: I used a production certificate and I also got the devices from GET /apps/{applicationId}/devices.

In the end the problem seems to have been with my push certificate. 

But the question still remains, is there an API endpoint to get the actual error. If that is possible I would have identified the faulty certificate earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, there is not a REST API call that will give additional error information.  However, if you open a Bluemix Support ticket, we can pull additional error information from the server logs using your AppGUID.

iOS certificate issues are one of the more common of invalid messages in the message report.

Answer (score 0):

@mihavr If the GET MessageID report (https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2cc73363-b50f-4b60-b2f9-c483ff5cd414/messages/8d58f4e/report) gives you invalid status for IOS device that means the problem seems to have been with push certificate is invalid and that generates invalid token when you register the ios device. Hence send message failed to deliver the message on the device and the messageID report shows Invalid status.

{
  "invalid": 2,
  "sent": 2,
  "ios": {
    "invalid": 2,
    "sent": 2
  }
}